# Elasticsearch constant score sort

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have a pretty simple elasticsearch query where I filter some items by category. It's a constant score query, something like this:

```
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "category": "[category-id]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that having no score to sort these result by they don't always come back in the same order. And this is an issue, because it messes up my pagination.

An example. I request the first 5 items and I receive back let's say the following ids: `[4, 7, 8, 10, 3]`. I then want the next 5 items to display the next page, but I may get some items repeated, like this: `[12, 15, 7, 13, 9]`.

The problem is that all my fields are string fields, and I wouldn't want to sort by any of them. The sort order is not important, it's just important to keep the same order every time.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Scroll API

you can simply use the [scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) API. it is generally used for retrieving all documents, considering the possible query and filters you applied.

So you won't need any sorting field.

[here](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/elasticsearch-get-all-documents/#:%7E:text=The%20Scroll%20API%20is%20a%20useful%20tool%20for,at%20the%20time%20of%20the%20initial%20search%20request.) is also a more detailed practical explanation, from Opster group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "category": "[category-id]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since this is what used to be known as a filtered query no scores are calculated and the score field will have value of 0.